# Display 2 tablix in SSRS 1 for paramter and the other for previous value of parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

Im working on report for a periodic form..
Its form that be collected every Quarter of year
Q1 2021
Q2 2021
Q3 2021

I want to make a report for multiple indicators that is displayed on tablix based on Quarter user choose using single choice parameter

Quarter: Q2 2021

Q2 2021
Tablix 1 data

But the challenge for me is to display automatically a previous Quarter to compare
When I choose a specific parameter value

Quarter: Q2 2021

Q2 2021
Tablix 1 data

Q1 2021
Tablix 2 data

Any ideas How to do it
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Whether you do it in the SQL or in an SSRS filter, the Quarter parameter year and quarter would need to be parsed out, the quarter subtracted, and then converted back to the correct format. I am assuming that you already have a field to use the parameter.

```
WHERE Q IN (@QUARTER, 
            'Q' + 
            CAST(CAST(ISNULL(NULLIF(SUBSTRING(@QUARTER, 2, 1), '1'), '5') AS INT) - 1 AS CHAR(1)) + ' ' + 
            CAST(CAST(RIGHT(@QUARTER, 4) AS INT) - IIF(SUBSTRING(@QUARTER, 2, 1) = '1', 1, 0) AS CHAR(4))
            )
```

This will create the previous Q by taking the quarter of the parameter, converting to NULL if it's one, then if null, convert the q to a 5 and subtract 1 to get the correct quarter. It adds a space and then the year, subtracting a year if the q was 1.

Comment: Thank you for your answer… it will have an issue when you look at year…between quarter 4 and 1 but any way i can handle that..but my source is SSAS so my query is mdx query